# Confusion regarding passing a SOAP related XML request:

Tags: soap, coldfusion, wsdl

I have the following message available in the WSDL:

```
<message name="checklookupRequest">
  <part name="mobileNumber" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="userName" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
</message>
```

I have created the following request inside the body tag of coldfusion page:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="soapBody">
<cfoutput>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:p1  = "https://abcd/checkLookup.php?wsdl" >
 <soap:Header>
   </soap:Header>

<soap:Body>

           <p1:checklookupRequest>

               <phonenumber>4135671234</phonenumber>
               <username>test</username>
               <password>password</password> 





           </p1:checklookupRequest>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>

</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
```

My question is that, I am using username and password in the `cfhttp` tag as well. So, it seems like I am bound to send username and password as a part of message invocation and as a part of `cfhttp` requirements. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

P.S: I don't have any Web API documentation available for the Web Service I am using.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Sure. If we consider the `cfhttp` documentation (http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_g-h_09.html), it has `username` and `password` attributes. And the method I am considering invoking with name `checklookuprequest` also has username and password requirements. So, I am sending username and password two times. Just wondering is it required?

Comment: _I don't have any Web API documentation available for the Web Service I am using._ And neither do we so we do not know what your endpoint requires. Without documentation you are left with trial-and-error. You will have to see what works and what doesn't by trying different things.